# Javascript Validation in Joomla Component

Tags: validation, joomla2.5

```
      <script language="javascript">

function myValidate(f) {
        if (document.formvalidator.isValid(f)) {
            f.task.value='save';
            f.submit(); 
        }
        else {
                alert('Error!');
                return false;
        }
        return false;
}
</script>
```

Putting form action as : : below

`<form action="index.php" onsubmit="return myValidate(this);" class="form-validate" method="post" name="adminForm" id="adminForm">`

Its working on this comment submit button very fine, not on save & Close in joomla

```
<!--<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit" />
-->
<input type="hidden" name="option" value="com_result" />
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $this->result->id; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="task" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="controller" value="result10" />
```

Not working in Joomla Component.Saving the form  On Ok Button of Error Alert. any suggestion ?

Comment: return false; not working below the alert. Any suggestion Please ?

Comment: Hm. Strange. Any errors in console?

Comment: NOT a single error i am finding out, Any suggestion its still saving the form with NULL values after pop alert of Error !

Comment: That looks strange. It works for me fine [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Suau7/3/). Possibly you have some other events calling submit. I would start profiling in chrome and check what functions are called after submit